# RCTBridgeModule not found - RNGoogleSignin

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I am trying to incorporate the react native Google sign in flow into my app but I am having trouble getting `RNGoogleSignin` to cooperate with me...

I've used rnpm to link up `react-native-google-signin` with my project but for some reason, `RNGoogleSignin.h` keeps complaining

```
"RCTBridgeModule.h" file not found
```

I've tried to add the correct headers - this `BridgeModule` is in my
    **`/node_modules/react-native/React/Base`**
directory but adding that to my Header search paths does not seem to fix the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What's your react-native version ?

I had the same issue while trying a simple bridge with a swift module after a fresh `react-native init myproject`, this fix it :

Since react-native 0.40 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.40.0 :

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

should be now :

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

And to make it work **I also needed to run** `react-native upgrade` **from command line** in my project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, and I resolve it with the following steps:

1- update pods with `pod update`

2- then re-install the pods with the following code

```
pod deintegrate {YOUR_PROJECT}.xcodeproj && rm -rf ./Pods && pod install
```

Then in the Xcode make sure of the following:

**Disable the parallel builds:**

Xcode menu -> Product -> Scheme -> Manage Shemes...
Double click on your application
Build tab -> uncheck Parallelize Build

**Add react as a project dependecy**

Xcode Project Navigator -> drag React.xcodeproj from Libraries to root tree
Build Phases Tab -> Target Dependencies -> + -> add React

Clean your project in Xcode with (cmd + shift + k)

Hope this will resolve your issue